# Navy Wheel Chocks - Additional Patents?

Tags: military

In reference to the patent: [US3189127](https://www.google.com/patents/US3189127)

I have been conducting research about the navy wheel chocks and have been only able to find this patent.  Are there any additional patents out there with regards to the modified tread pattern? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could do a patent search on wheel chocks. A good place to start would be the [patents that cite](https://patents.google.com/patent/US3189127#citedBy) this patent. As you can see, this patent cites 5 earlier patents as is cited by 7 later patents and one application. Look at those patents/applications and then look at the citations for those. Repeat as necessary.